# How to get Response Data when using xhrPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dojo

I have written the following code to pass parameters to the server, and to get response back.

Actually, my Response should be a Report to print on the grid.

When debugging the code, the debugger is going inside load parameter, but I am not understanding how to get required report data.

Please also suggest me if I am moving in the right direction.

```
function SearchUser() {
    var userName = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;
    var firstName = document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("txtLastName").value;
    var applicationName = document.getElementById("txtApplicationName").value;
    var roleName = document.getElementById("txtRoleName").value;
    var locationType = document.getElementById("txtLocationType").value;
    var location = document.getElementById("txtLocation").value;
    var userType = document.getElementById("txtUserType").value;
    var isAdmin = document.getElementById("chkAdmin").checked;
    //ValidateSearchUser();
    //var str = "User name: " + userName + ", First name: " + firstName + "Last name: " + lastName + ", App. name: " + applicationName + ", Role: " + roleName + ", Location type: " + locationType + ", Location: " + location + ", User type: " + userType + ", Is Admin? " + isAdmin + "\nSearch functionality yet to be developed.";
    //alert(str);

    var searchUserParameters = { "pageIndex": "1", "pageSize": "100", "userName": ""+ userName +"", "firstName":""+ firstName +"", "lastName":""+ lastName +"", "userType":""+ userType +"", "appName":""+ applicationName +"", "roleName":""+ roleName +"", "LocationType":""+ locationType +"", "location":""+ location +"", "isAdmin":""+ isAdmin +"" };

    var xhrArgs = {
        //url: "postIt",
        postData: dojo.toJson(searchUserParameters),
        handleAs: "json",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" },
        load: function (data) {
           //I am not understanding what code to write here.
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("SVS error:" + error);
        }
    }


    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);



    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why is the `url` parameter of your arguments commented out?  The URL should be the controller and action you are targeting with this request and that will return the report data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my code like below, now the problem got solved. Thanks for all to those who have tried for my requirement.

```
    var xhrArgs = {
        postData: dojo.toJson(searchUserParameters),
        handleAs: "text",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" },
        load: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("searchUserOutput").innerHTML = data;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("SVS error:" + error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you were able to resolve it using what I described.  How about an upvote or accepting my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the server side code implemented already you should be receiving the data back in the `data` parameter of your load function handler.  The `handleAs` parameter is set to `json` meaning it is expecting to receive the response data in that format.  Exactly how you handle the data on the client side will depend on how you have structured it on the server side.  You say the response data should be a report to print on the grid, then what you need to do is get that report out of the `data` parameter and add it to the DOM.  How you do this exactly again will depend on what exactly you have returned from the server, i.e. preformatted HTML, raw data to format into HTML, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your server answers properly report data will be passed to `load` callback, already parsed, i.e. as an object.

Checkout [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/6ZTpt/) to see a working example.

Alternatively, you can return `deferred` from the function and process data in `then` callback, as you can see in the aforementioned jsFiddle.